# cs50 pset5 memory leak when in unload function, when freeing memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks, hashtable, cs50

I am currently working on [cs50 pset5](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/).

I have encountered a memory leak when I attempt to free all the memory I have located in the program.
The error seems to occur in my `unload` function, where it `malloc` for pointer `cursor`.
If anyone can provide me directions on how to approach this issue, please let me know.
I have also provided comments to my code to highlight what it is doing.

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 50;

node *table[N] = {NULL};

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // allocate memory for struct type `node` pointer 
    node *cursor = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));                 // MEMORY LEAK happens here !!!! :(
    node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    // if memory cannot be allocated successfully, return false
    if (cursor == NULL || tmp == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // iterate the table for N'times (N = 50, for now)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // if the table has nothing inside the i'th bucket, return false 
        // this means, table has no linked list inside i'th bucket 
        if (table[i] == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // assign tmp pointer to the head node, and cursor to anything next to tmp 
            tmp = table[i];
            cursor = tmp;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            // free memory for tmp pointer 
            free(tmp);

            // continue traversing the linked list until cursor pointer points to NULL (end of the linked list)
            while (cursor != NULL)
            {
                tmp = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->next;
                free(tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    // free memory for cursor
    free(cursor);
    return true;
}
```

The error I get, after running, `help50 valgrind ./speller dictionaries/small texts/cat.txt`.

```
==14685== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14685== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14685== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14685== Command: ./speller dictionaries/small texts/cat.txt
==14685== 
32
==14685== Invalid write of size 1
==14685==    at 0x40121F: hash (dictionary.c:67)
==14685==    by 0x401354: load (dictionary.c:99)
==14685==    by 0x400A2B: main (speller.c:41)
==14685==  Address 0x55cc88a is 2 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4011D5: hash (dictionary.c:61)
==14685==    by 0x401354: load (dictionary.c:99)
==14685==    by 0x400A2B: main (speller.c:41)
==14685== 
==14685== Invalid read of size 1
==14685==    at 0x40122C: hash (dictionary.c:68)
==14685==    by 0x401354: load (dictionary.c:99)
==14685==    by 0x400A2B: main (speller.c:41)
==14685==  Address 0x55cc88a is 2 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4011D5: hash (dictionary.c:61)
==14685==    by 0x401354: load (dictionary.c:99)
==14685==    by 0x400A2B: main (speller.c:41)
==14685== 
19

MISSPELLED WORDS

47
A
32
20
is
27
not
47
a
==14685== Invalid write of size 1
==14685==    at 0x40121F: hash (dictionary.c:67)
==14685==    by 0x401124: check (dictionary.c:32)
==14685==    by 0x400D50: main (speller.c:114)
==14685==  Address 0x55cdf9a is 2 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4011D5: hash (dictionary.c:61)
==14685==    by 0x401124: check (dictionary.c:32)
==14685==    by 0x400D50: main (speller.c:114)
==14685== 
==14685== Invalid read of size 1
==14685==    at 0x40122C: hash (dictionary.c:68)
==14685==    by 0x401124: check (dictionary.c:32)
==14685==    by 0x400D50: main (speller.c:114)
==14685==  Address 0x55cdf9a is 2 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4011D5: hash (dictionary.c:61)
==14685==    by 0x401124: check (dictionary.c:32)
==14685==    by 0x400D50: main (speller.c:114)
==14685== 
19

WORDS MISSPELLED:     4
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  2
WORDS IN TEXT:        6
TIME IN load:         0.03
TIME IN check:        0.00
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.03

==14685== 
==14685== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14685==     in use at exit: 1,000 bytes in 9 blocks
==14685==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 14 frees, 10,944 bytes allocated
==14685== 
==14685== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4013F1: unload (dictionary.c:128)
==14685==    by 0x400ED0: main (speller.c:154)
==14685== 
==14685== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4013FF: unload (dictionary.c:129)
==14685==    by 0x400ED0: main (speller.c:154)
==14685== 
==14685== 336 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x401131: check (dictionary.c:33)
==14685==    by 0x400D50: main (speller.c:114)
==14685== 
==14685== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x5258E49: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==14685==    by 0x5258E49: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==14685==    by 0x4012DE: load (dictionary.c:83)
==14685==    by 0x400A2B: main (speller.c:41)
==14685== 
==14685== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14685==    definitely lost: 448 bytes in 8 blocks
==14685==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14685==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14685==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==14685==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14685== 
==14685== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14685== ERROR SUMMARY: 15 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Asking for help...

==14685== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==14685==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14685==    by 0x4013F1: unload (dictionary.c:128)
==14685==    by 0x400ED0: main (speller.c:154)

Looks like your program leaked 56 bytes of memory. Did you forget to free memory that you allocated via malloc? Take a closer look at line 128 of dictionary.c.
```

**So why does memory leak happen?** 
[A memory leak happens when a programmer creates a memory from heap but forgets to free it.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-memory-leak-how-can-we-avoid/)

However, in my code, I have free'd both `cursor` and `tmp` pointer after it's used.
I do not know why I am encountering the error, although I am freeing it at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "MEMORY LEAK happens here !!!!" as you say.

You allocated two buffers, but later their pointers are overwritten by `table[i]` without being freed. This is memory leak.

To avoid memory leak, stop allocating unused buffers.

The part

```
    // allocate memory for struct type `node` pointer 
    node *cursor = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));                 // MEMORY LEAK happens here !!!! :(
    node *tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    // if memory cannot be allocated successfully, return false
    if (cursor == NULL || tmp == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

should be just

```
    // allocate memory for struct type `node` pointer 
    node *cursor;
    node *tmp;
```

The memory for pointer is allocated on the stack.

Also the part

```
    // free memory for cursor
    free(cursor);
```

should be removed because the list is already freed and the memory for cursor will be automatically freed (from the stack) on returning from the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your answer is indeed interesting, and I would like to ask you another question about what you wrote here. So, you said `overwritten by table[i] without being freed`, which I believe you are referring to the code on `tmp = table[i];`. Why can't I overwrite the pointer? Actually, what I was trying to do is, having `tmp` to point to whatever `table[i]` is pointing to. Which means, I am simply passing the memory address `table[i]` holds, to `tmp`. Why isn't this allowed? Both `table[i]` and `tmp` are the same data types, which is a pointer to `node`.(node is a struct type)

Comment: **Simply** passing the memory address `table[i]` holds to `tmp` is do allowed. What is bad is allocating unused buffer and throwing its address stored in `tmp` away by assigning new address without freeing the buffer.